# Formula to Trigger Checkbox if Date Meets Criteria

Tags: formula-field, custom-field

I am looking for formula to check if created date is less than 90 days then checkbox should be marked as true using formula field. Please help me on this.

I am creating 2 formula fields.

- 1st field for calculating 90 days ago from created date

> DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) - 90(X90Days__c api name)

- 2nd field for checkbox, see below:

> IF(X90Days__c <> null, True, False)

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Community!!. Could you please help to edit your question and add what you have tried and where you stuck on this requirement? We are good to help you to overcome the stopping point but not to provide complete solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: @MohanrajSivalingam, 
I am creating 2 formula fields. 1st field for calculating 90 days ago from created date and 2nd field for checkbox, see below:

1. DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) - 90(X90Days__c api name)
2. IF(X90Days__c <> null, True, False)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's need to used on `TODAY()` function in your formula. You're formula will be,

```
X90Days__c = TODAY() - CreatedDate // It's provide the # of days from creation
```

then you can use the field value `X90Days__c` into your check box like,

```
IF (X90Days__c < 90, TRUE, FALSE) // if X90Days__c is Number datatype
IF ((TODAY() - 90 > X90Days__c), TRUE, FALSE) // if X90Days__c is Date/Datetime datatype
```

But you can able to use those 2 formulas in 1 (if the X90Days__c is just created for this checkbox value) as follows,

```
IF ((TODAY() - CreatedDate) < 90, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If I  use IF (X90Days__c < 90, TRUE, FALSE) then getting Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected Date, received Number

Comment: May I know, what is the datatype for the field `X90Days__c`, Is it `Number` or `Date`?

Comment: I have updated the answer for the above 2 datatypes also. Please check and let me know any issues.

Comment: I used Date datatype